# How do I show that $\gcd(n,\frac{n}{k})=\frac{n}{k}$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> $\gcd(n,\frac{n}{k})=\frac{n}{k}$

Let $n, k$ be positive integers.

This should be a trivial question but not having taken any classes in number theory I would like to be convinced with a simple proof that the above holds true.

Could someone kindly provide me with a proof?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take $n = 10$, $k = 2$.

Comment: Is there a more general one?

Comment: What do you mean by a more general one? The statement you are trying to prove does not always hold.

Comment: The gcd of $n$ and $n/k$ is $n/k$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas And I thought what went wrong. Dam typos. Edit made
May I request for a simple proof please?

Comment: It is obvious that $n/k$ divides both. And nothing bigger can divide both.

Comment: If $k | n$, then $\frac{n}{k} | n$, so gcd = $\frac{n}{k}$

Comment: For completeness, there should be a hypothesis (currently unmentioned) that $k$ divides $n$, or equivalently that $\frac nk$ is an integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$n/k$ is obviously divisible by $n/k$, and so is $n$, because $n = k \cdot (n/k)$. This is their greatest common divisor, because $n/k$ doesn't have any bigger divisor than $n/k$ itself.

Answer (score 0):

Let dis the common divisor of n and n/k.So $d|n\;\;and\;\;d|{\frac{n}{k}}$.

So,we take the linear combination ${\implies}$ $nx+{\frac{n}{k}}y=d$.

We know that n=$dk_1$ and ${\frac{n}{k}}=dk_2$.Now we put the value of

n=$dk_1$ in the equation.We get ${k_1}x+{k_2}y=1$.Hence GCD$(k_1,k_2)=1$

and $k_1\;\;and\;\;k_2 $are coprime to each other.We have $\frac{dk_1}{k}=dk_2$.

So $k_2=\frac{k_1}{k}$.Though $k_2$ is a multiple of $k_1$, $k_1$ does not

divide $k_2$.Hence $\frac{k_1}{k}=1$ and $k_1=k$ and we get n=$dk_1$$\implies$

n=$dk$$\implies$d=$\frac{n}{k}$.Now you have to prove that d is the greatest.

Then you are done.

Answer (score 0):

The largest number which divides both the numbers $n/k$ and $n$ is $gcd(n,n/k)$.
Here, we can easily observe that $n/k$ divides both $n$ and $n/k$. Also, any number greater than $n/k$ cannot be $gcd(n,n/k)$, since any such number cannot divide $n/k$. Hence, $gcd(n,n/k)=n/k$.